# Why didn't they just spare Michael out of the cage?

Tags: supernatural

Now Angels are fighting and killing each other just because they need RULES and A LEADER, and Michael definitely is the leader.

**Why not just spare him and then every problem will be solved quite well?**

Comment: Agreed. The only archangel that was left over (as far as I know) was Raphael. Had he been successful in springing EVEN Michael from the cage - Michael, being one that wanted to go through with the battle would have in turn, let loose Lucifer as well. Even if he didn't right away, it would have been yet another problem for the Winchesters to handle, & as it is, there are just enough stories going on - so it would have overcrowded the storylines of each individual season that ensued after that event. I'd like for Michael (and Adams') story to come out more as well, and even just have Michael get

Answer (score 1):

As far as we know, the angels can't open the cage themselves. The cage was made specifically to hold an *archangel* until such time as the criteria were met to allow it to open, and it was locked with the rings from the Four Horseman of the Apocalypse (at least one of whom outranks the angels). It ultimately required a human to open the cage the first time (to break the first and last seals). At this point, I don't think we have any idea what's required to open the cage now, though I assume they can just break another 66 seals. Whatever it takes to open the cage, I doubt the angels have the power to do it.

Even if they did that, it would let Michael and Lucifer out of the cage, and the angels couldn't stop them. Both of them can overpower any non-archangel without breaking a sweat. Doing so would restart the apocalypse that Sam and Dean halted by throwing the angels into the cage to begin with. At this point, I believe that the faction that actually wanted the Apocalypse to happen lost the war in Heaven to Castiel and is mostly dead, so the remaining angels probably don't want Earth to end, they just want to get back to Heaven.